# Can anyone explain this javaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Please explain me the below line

```
document.CreateUserForm.elements[ controlName ].value = volumeObject
```

Comment: You need to supply the context as well. How is this being used? Also, try to ask a more specific question. What part do you understand and what not?

Comment: Hi, consider to use JQuery instead using directly javascript you will find a lot of incompatibility in other cases. Your snippet seems sets an array value... but what do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's an "early syntax" of accessing form element value where `CreateUserForm` is the name of the form, which has an array of elements with `controlName` as the name of single element.

Nowadays you could access it for instance: `document.querySelector("[name="+ controlName +"]).value` or `document.getElementsByName(controlName)[0].value`.

Comment: Be careful with `getElementsByName` as in some browsers it will include elements with a matching `id=""` attribute value, not just `name=""`.

Comment: The "early" syntax does still wok and should be preffered (in my eyes), if you want to get or set values for form vields. Btw. the first version of this syntax is `document.forms[<formname>].elements[<controlname>].value`